# WebView - Want to open in app not in browser

Tags: android, browser, webview

I have a problem. I created some app, which should open my website, but when I run the app on my phone, its ask me in which browser I want to open it(Google Chrome...). But I want that website is open in app, not in browser... I'm working with Android Studio 1.1.0... Here is my code in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView MyWeb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    MyWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyWeb.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    MyWeb.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
} }
```

P.S. I changed the url to the fake one...

Comment: Don't forget to not link to external images, as the question will become meaningless to future visitors when that page goes away.

Comment: Okey... I just wanted to post it if someone won't uderstand my problem... I removed it now

Comment: Do anyone of you have any idea, how to slove this? I just want that webpage will open in app, not in browser.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line of code before your MyWeb.loadUrl

```
MyWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

This worked for me.!

Comment: The text style is a bit misleading because MyWeb should be a class, but it is working :)